# How to get the children of a CarouselView?

Tags: xamarin.forms, carousel

I have added a "Label" as children to CarouselView through ItemTemplate property of a CarouselView in Xamarin.Forms. So, is there any way to get the children of that CarouselView when I move to the next page in that CarouselView?

Any Advise?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for. Do you want to change the label text when it is moved to that page? Please be more specific of what you are trying to do. What are you using as ItemsSource for that carousel?

Comment: Yes. I just load a Label with Text = "Text". I want to change that text to "NextText" when I move to the next page.

Comment: Is the label you want to change on current page? Then there is no point if you are navigating away. So I assume it is or next page? You can pass this text via constructor or setter and then using event from my answer below set you label

Comment: did you find a solution? Can you share your code

Answer (score 1):

You can use PositionSelected or ItemSelected events of CarouselView to find currently selected child view.

Answer (score 1):

There is a property in the Carrousel called VisibleViews that returns the list of the carrousel child elements.

```
CarouselView carrusel = new CarouselView();
List<View> childElemests = carrusel.VisibleViews.ToList();
```